# PHP date() returns different timezones for different timestamps

Tags: php, date, timezone

I've faced a very weird behaviour of php `date()` function.

See this code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Melbourne');
echo date('P', 1475000000) . ' ' . date('P', 1475700000);
```

It returns `+10:00 +11:00`
While it must be always `+10:00`. Unix timestamps don't content timezone in it that's why `date()` must return just currently configured timezone.

PHP version 5.6.23

Any ideas why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.australia.gov.au/about-australia/facts-and-figures/time-zones-and-daylight-saving

Your second timestamp is with DST. The first one is not yet.

Comment: @Stalinko Thanks. At first I also thought that it was something weird, untill I saw the date, and thought of DST. And when I found the Australian DST information, I knew enough. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer.

It's because Australia changes time on 2nd October. One timestamp is before it, while another is after, that's why all correct.
Thanks all for attention.